# Google Maps hook into desiredTilt_changed event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have a Google maps on our website and would like to handle when a user selects or deselects the 45 degree option on satellite-type map views. Through some experimentation and console.logs, I have found what looks like to be an internal only method called desiredTilt_changed which seems to change a desiredTilt property only when the checkbox is clicked. This looks like exactly what we need, however I am seeing nothing on the Google Maps API reference or when I search the web. All they mention on the API docs is the tilt property and tilt_changed event-which fires when zooming to a level which allows (if available) a 45 degree view, as well as when the checkbox is clicked. Has anyone either had experience tapping into this desiredTilt_changed event, or some other way of distinguishing in tilt_changed if it was the checkbox being clicked or not? Thanks in advance! :)